# Vim fugitive autocmd not added

Tags: vim

I'm starting to use Vim 8 and work on setting up my .vimrc. I installed `vim-fugitive` using `vim-plug`. I can use the commands provided by the plugin. My problem is that I want to define custom commands to serve as git aliases. I followed this issue: https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/72 but when I try to use the command added by my `autocmd` call I get an error: `not an editor command`. I understood that it could be a timing problem between the plugin load and the command declaration but I wrote my `autocmd` after the plugin load by `vim-plug`. Here is an extract of my `.vimrc`:

```
" Installing/loading plugins
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
    [...]
    Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
call plug#end()

" #########################################################
" #
" #                      Fugitive
" #
" #########################################################
augroup gitAlias
    " Remove all gitAlias command
    " Needed because they are added every time otherwise
    autocmd!
    autocmd User fugitive command! -nargs=0 Gpr :G pull --rebase
augroup END
```

If I run `:command! -nargs=0 Gpr :G pull --rebase` while in Vim, the custom command works. Perhaps the problem comes from the `autocmd` event but I can't find a way to make sure the event exists.

Comment: See `:help User`.

Comment: Thanks @romainl. I did check the documentation and from what I understood `autocmd` declared on the `User` group are not run automatically but only when a call to `doautocmd` is performed. I believe that's the job of vim-fugitive to call `doautocmd` with the fugitive event. I looked at the source code and I found this line: https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/3eb6f316c09553989e59bb3802da100a6fb7c091/plugin/fugitive.vim#L286. I added an "F" to the event name and also moved the augroup before the `plug#begin` call but it didn't change anything. The command is still not available.

Comment: [By the looks of it](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/3eb6f316c09553989e59bb3802da100a6fb7c091/plugin/fugitive.vim#L362), the plugin does that a new file is edited that is in a Git directory. Is that the case?

Comment: Thanks @romainl it seems to be the case indeed. I was probably testing it wrong. I expected the command to be always available within Vim even without a file open as long as the pwd was in a git repo.
I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

After discussing with Romainl the commands now work for me. It was perhaps a combination of a missing capital letter on the command event and that I was not testing at the right place.

If you look at the code here: https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/3eb6f316c09553989e59bb3802da100a6fb7c091/plugin/fugitive.vim#L362. The `FugitiveDetect` function is called only on `BufNewFile,BufReadPost` events. This means the commands are available only when editing an existing file or a new one in a `git` repo. I initially thought the command where always available.

Thanks Romainl for your help.